# Issue with typedefining iterators with in the class declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, incomplete-type

I'm working on a legacy code which is poorly written and only compiles within Microsoft Visual Studios and with Visual C++ compiler. GCC, G++, or Clang all fails to compile the code due to build time errors. I have narrowed down the issue to the following class declaration which instantiate a `STL` container of the `class type`  within the class declaration:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>

#include <unordered_map>
#include <bits/unique_ptr.h>

#define HASH_MAP unordered_map

using namespace std;

namespace XYZ {
       class abc {
           public:
              typedef HASH_MAP<double, abc> MAP; // This is the problem ?
              typedef MAP::iterator Iterator;
              typedef MAP::const_iterator ConstIterator;
              typedef pair<double, abc> Pair;

              bool less(abc::Pair& a, abc::Pair& b) { return a.first < b.first; }

           public:
              abc() {}
              ~abc() { }

       };
    }
```

I want to know what is the best way to refactor this code segment while preserving the structure of the code. For example, I was trying to make the `MAP` definition with a pointer type (i.e., `typedef HASH_MAP<double, XYZ*> MAP`) This change worked with GCC compiler however, since, I'm changing to pointer type I would have to dig deep in to the code base and modify most of the code base as this class is playing a key role in other dependent code.

So I was wondering if there is an alternative to fix this issue which would not require significant change to the original code base. I was thinking in the line of making a `friend` class similar.

Following is the compiler error:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:60,
                 from /home/user/work/wxy.h:4,
                 from /home/user/work/abc.h:4,
                 from /home/user/work/abc.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits:615:28:   required from ‘struct std::__is_destructible_impl<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc> >’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits:637:12:   required from ‘struct std::__is_destructible_safe<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc>, false, false>’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits:652:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_destructible<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc> >’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits:116:12:   required from ‘struct std::__and_<std::is_destructible<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc> >, std::__is_direct_constructible_impl<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc>, const std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc>&> >’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits:817:12:   required from ‘struct std::__is_direct_constructible_new_safe<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc>, const std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc>&>’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits:895:12:   [ skipping 4 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits:968:12:   required from ‘struct std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc>, false>’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits:974:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_copy_constructible<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc> >’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/alloc_traits.h:540:12:   required from ‘struct std::__is_copy_insertable<std::allocator<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc> > >’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/alloc_traits.h:560:63:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Alloc> using __check_copy_constructible = std::__allow_copy_cons<std::__is_copy_insertable<_Alloc>::value> [with _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const double, XYZ::abc> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unordered_map.h:97:11:   required from ‘class std::unordered_map<double, XYZ::abc>’
/home/user/work/abc.h:27:20:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:102:11: error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
       _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
           ^
In file included from /home/user/work/abc.cpp:1:0:
/home/user/work/abc.h:24:11: error: forward declaration of ‘class XYZ::abc’
     class abc {
           ^
```

Comment: How can a namespace possibly be a template argument to `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: that is just a `typedef` no instantiation

Comment: I'm curious why `public:` is declared twice? And either class `abc` or `namespace XYZ` is missing a left `}`.

Comment: @user2079303 it must be a typo, the other class methods are also `XYZ()` and `~XYZ()`

Comment: I fixed the issue with the left braces. It was a typo.

Comment: What does compiler say?

Comment: It was my mistake. It is not namespace...in fact it was a class. It was a typo

Comment: This is the compiler error:

Comment: error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
       _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
           ^

Comment: Updated the post with the compiler error

Comment: Did you `#include <utility>`?  Are you using `using namespasce std;`?  If not then all names from the standard library need to have `std::` before the name.

Comment: if you will not show minimal code which reproduce the problem, nobody can help you.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried using  `#include<utility>` but that didn't help. I'm using `using namespace std;` Updated the code to show that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is (for whatever reasons -- hell, it's just a typedef!) with the Iterators. If you move those out of your class code, so that the class definition is complete at the point of their definition, it compiles (with g++). Perhaps one then should rename `Iterator` to `MAP_Iterator` or such. I can imagine that the changes required in client code then are manageable

Edit: After your comment I had the idea to put the iterator typedefs in a class called `abc` (the original class name) to retain source compatibility with the client code. The actual class definition is moved to a base class which the client code doesn't need to use explicitly. The map holds objects of the base class, which involves slicing and back conversion when storing or retrieving true `abc`s. It would probably not be possible to hold `abc` references to values in the map, but the simple value-based example below (using the iterators) works. There are a few comments in the source code.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// The "original" abc
class abcBase 
{
       public:

        typedef unordered_map<double, abcBase> MAP; // This is the problem ?
          typedef pair<double, abcBase> Pair;
          bool less(abcBase::Pair& a, abcBase::Pair& b) { return a.first < b.first; }
          string tag;
       public:
          abcBase(string t): tag(t){}
          abcBase() = default;
          ~abcBase() { }
};

// The abc presented to the users for source compatibility.
// There is a conversion
// from base to derived via constructor. 
//
// Note that a MAP
// holds abcBase objects, not abc objects! We need to convert them
// when we store and when we read.
// Conversion derived -> base is via slicing
// (which does not do any harm as long as we do not define
// data members in derived).
class abc: public abcBase
{
    public:
    // conversion constructor
    abc(const abcBase &b): abcBase(b){}
    abc(string t): abcBase(t){}
    abc() = default;
    typedef MAP::iterator Iterator;
    typedef MAP::const_iterator ConstIterator;
};

int main()
{
    abc::MAP m;
    abc a("a"),b("b"),c("c");
    m[1.0] = a; // conversion abc -> abcBase ...
    m[2.0] = b;
    m[3.0] = c;

    a = m[1.0]; // conversion abcBase -> abc via ctor

    for( abc::Iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "key: " << i->first << ", val: " << i->second.tag << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. It did compile this code but in client code it fails since the `iterator` is not part of this class. So whenever a class instance is declared and its iterator is called it complains. Any suggestions for making `iterators` part of the class?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your solution fixed the issue. Using namespace identifier for client code.

Comment: Ah, good! I just posted an updated solution with a derived class construction, but it is something of a hack...

Answer (score 0):

You're using `std::unordered_map` so you're using C++11.

So I suppose that the use of `std::unique_ptr` (`typedef HASH_MAP<double, std::unique_ptr<XYZ>> MAP` instead of `typedef HASH_MAP<double, XYZ*> MAP`) can help you a lot in reducing the following modifications.

By example, the following code compile

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

#define HASH_MAP unordered_map 

namespace abc {
   class XYZ {
      private:
         int  _test;

      public:
         typedef HASH_MAP<double, std::unique_ptr<XYZ>> MAP; // This is the problem ?
         typedef MAP::iterator Iterator;
         typedef MAP::const_iterator ConstIterator;
         typedef pair<double, std::unique_ptr<XYZ>> Pair;

         bool less(XYZ::Pair& a, XYZ::Pair& b) { return a.first < b.first; }

      public:
         XYZ():_test(0) {}
         ~XYZ() { }

         // Some function definitions
   };
};


int main ()
 {
   return 0;
 }
```

Obviously I'm supposing your namespace is `abc` and your class name is `XYZ`; you can't put a namespace in a map.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Using `unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer would be better style, but would it reduce the required amount of changes in the client code?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - not a lot but can avoid the `delete` part

Comment: @max66 thanks for the solution. I took the pointer route before.. not the `unique_ptr` but raw pointers. Seems like it requires significant changes to the client code base.

Comment: @kishansudu - you're welcome; if your map/pairs aren't in `XYZ` class (if `XYZ` is the class), you can put typedefs outside the class (see the answer from Peter A. Schneider); if you have to put maps/pairs as members of `XYZ`, I don't know how to avoid significant changes

Comment: @max66 Thank! No they are not members of the class. Just the typedefs so I'll try Peter A. Schneider's suggestion.